# Участник на протяжении 42 дня (в профиле)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

Увидел профиль [участника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227438/elizabeth-nepomozhets) и заметил этот баг.
Некорректная форма рядом с числительным, должно быть: на протяжении 42 (сорока двух) *дней*.

> [image: Скриншот примера]

Comment: Как обычно, уже есть [дубликат](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/910/176217) с ожидаемым [meta-tag:статус-завершено].

Comment: Фикс породил [другую проблему](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288810/339911).

Comment: @alexolut Русский язык сложней английского. Бывает:(

Comment: Баг в локализации вскрылся на самом деле. Так что пусть наводят порядок, если действительно хотят развивать не только англоязычные сообщества.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В transifex есть 2 варианта, которые могут давать на выходе "42 дня":

- [$__count$ days](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263458?key=151e08c767c86417dff98389b214c673)
- [$Days$d](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266629?key=eddcbedd51123c3a3cf898a28e8e46bb)

Учитывая, что на enSO соответствующее поле выводится как:

> Member for 42 days

получается, что нужно править первый вариант. Это сделать не сложно, но для пущей надежности, конечно, хотелось бы чтобы разработчики ответили на [вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288470/339911) о том, какие строки вообще используются в данном контексте. Чтобы нам не приходилось блуждать в потёмках и выполнять перевод методом проб и ошибок.

Итоговый перевод:

- one:

  > $__count$ дня
- few:

  > $__count$ дней
- many (не менялся):

  > $__count$ дней

Должно стать доступно на сборке, новее чем rev 2016.12.21.1.

Comment: А данный алгоритм (one, few, many) учитывает, что при числах от 5 до 20 будет "дней"? Ну соответственно 105-120 и т.д.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov [учитывает](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1136/176217)